# Why are my object's fields set to default after deserializing with objectInputStream.readObject()?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

In Java, I have a simple class with three public (primitive) fields like so:

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable {
    public volatile float x, y, z;

    public MyObject() {
        this(0, 0, 0);
    }

    public MyObject(float x, float y, float z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public void set(float x, float y, float z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public void set(MyObject other) {
        set(other.x, other.y, other.z);
    }
}
```

I write objects to an object output stream like so:

```
public void write(MyObject myObject) {
    try {
        mObjectOutStream.writeObject(myObject);
        mObjectOutStream.flush();

        Log.d(TAG, "wrote myObject.x as:" + myObject.x);
        Log.d(TAG, "wrote myObject.y as:" + myObject.y);
        Log.d(TAG, "wrote myObject.z as:" + myObject.z);
    } catch (IOException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
    }
}
```

And, I read objects from an object input stream with a blocking call in a separate thread like so:

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            MyObject myObject = (MyObject) mObjectInStream.readObject();

            Log.d(TAG, "read myObject.x as:" + myObject.x);
            Log.d(TAG, "read myObject.y as:" + myObject.y);
            Log.d(TAG, "read myObject.z as:" + myObject.z);
        } catch (IOException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during read", e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during read", e);
        }
    }
}
```

And somehow, my logs show things like this:

```
BluetoothService: wrote myObject.x as: 0.37361085
BluetoothService: wrote myObject.y as: 0.87006456
BluetoothService: wrote myObject.z as: 1.7877682
BluetoothService: read myObject.x as: 0.0
BluetoothService: read myObject.y as: 0.0
BluetoothService: read myObject.z as: 0.0
```

I have tried declaring the fields as volatile to make sure they are thread safe, as well as implementing readObject and writeObject methods for the MyObject class, but none of this has helped.

I suspect (hope) that I'm missing something simple that someone could point out.

If it is relevant, I'm using Bluetooth sockets on Android. I have successfully sent String objects, but using `byte[]` as in the BluetoothChat example from the Android sample code. I have not been able to send my Serializable object.

Can someone point me in the right direction here, or possibly give me a hint about how to troubleshoot this issue? I don't know how to narrow down the issue beyond what I have logged so far.

Comment: Was it the first time you wrote this `MyObject` to the stream? If not, you will need to use `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` between writes, or `ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared().` See the Javadoc for why. NB your loop should terminate when you catch `EOFException`, and probably on any other `IOException` as well.

Comment: ```ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared()``` solved my issue it seems. If you post that as an answer, I will give you the accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it wasn't the first time you wrote this `MyObject` to the stream, you will need to use `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` between writes, or `ObjectOutputStream.writeUnshared().` See the Javadoc for why.

NB your loop should terminate when you catch `EOFException,` and probably on any other `IOException` as well.

Comment: I've spent hours on this, and you answer likely saved me hours more, and many headaches! Although I don't fully understand what is going on behind the scenes with Java object serialization, I'm very happy to finally have something that works.

Comment: If you re-serialize the same object it just sends a 'handle', for purposes of object graphs, so the object received by `readObject()` is the same *reference* that was acquired the first time, containing therefore both values. Both methods mentioned above bypass that.

Comment: I see. Thanks for following up. Does this mean that the object output stream holds references to all objects it has written, hence the memory concerns I've seen in related questions (some have suggested that ```ObjectOutputStream.reset()``` can help prevent memory leaks)?